# how to write a python code when you divide by 0 say False

Tags: python

How to write a python code so when you divide by 0 you get False.

Comment: Check the denominator before dividing and return `False` if it's 0

Comment: Why the unaccept?

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate the `ZeroDivisionError` by using `try/except`:

```
try:
    var = num/num2
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print False  
else:
    pass
```

You can try it [here](https://repl.it/EzCI/0). If using this within a function, you could replace `print` with `return`. For example:

```
def example(num, num2):
    try:
        solution = num/num2
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "False"
    else:
        return solution

print example(1, 0)
```

For length, you could use

```
if denominator == 0:
    print False
```

Comment: Never write functions, that return in case of error simply another type as error mark. That's why exceptions exist.

Comment: @Daniel It is just an example if the OP decides to use in a function not as a standalone functiob

Answer (score 2):

Pls read how to use [`try... except...`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Something like.

```
 try:
    0/0
 except ZeroDivisionError:
    False
```

Comment: I though you can only use `return` for functions

Comment: Of course, I depends on a task - return/print/yield/etc... Unfortunately autho didn't specify it properly. But if author understands the concept of `try... except`, he'll write correct code.

Comment: This returns `None`

Comment: Somehow I doubt that OP understands the concept of `try...except`. This isn't the sort of question that anyone who knows even a small amount of Python asks.

Comment: You are quite right, at a moment he has no such knowledge.  But he can obtain it in docs. Just to point  him to the right direction.

Comment: I agree -- hopefully they will learn something useful

Comment: @PythonMaster, thanks for the supposed editions. Though they were rejected, because I've edited post little bit before, they are good and useful. Thx. :thumbup:

Answer (score 1):

You could write an if statement to return False.

```
a = 5
b = 30
if a == 0:
    c = False
else:
    c = b / a
print c
```

Or you could define a function.

```
def divide(b, a):
    if a == 0:
        return False:
    return b / a
```

Or you could use a try and catch block as outlined in other answers

Comment: Well, you need a `print` statement in your first program since nothing is outputted

Comment: @PythonMaster I though that was trivial. But I added than just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two short expressions which evaluate to either `a/b` or `False`, depending on whether or not `b == 0`. As expressions, they can be embedded as subexpressions of a larger expression:

1) `a/b if b != 0 else False`

2) `b != 0 and a/b`

The second one works because Python `and` returns the first component if the first component is falsey otherwise it returns the second component.